# Combining multiple SELECT INTO results into one variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

The method I am using may not be efficient (or possible), if so please let me know.
I am trying to use `SELECT INTO` to select two values and then attach them to a variable (v1) which will be returned by the function as one cell.  Inserting `UNION ALL` between the two `SELECT INTO` statements results in an `ERROR: syntax error at or near "UNION"`

**EDIT** -  the function provides two unique values (not null) which are specified for these two SELECT INTO statements

**desired output:**

```
    v1             v2      v3    etc.
2678, 2987
```

**excerpt from function:**

```
SELECT value
    INTO v1
    FROM table
    WHERE year <= parameteryear;

SELECT value
    INTO v1
    FROM table    
    WHERE yearinteger >= parameteryear;

data := v1;
RETURN NEXT;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: In Postgres, `select into` is used to create tables, not to assign values to variables.  I am unclear on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @GordonLinoffin PL/pgSQL `select .. into` is definitely used to put values into variables. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

Comment: you want v1 to be a string with two numbers and a comma between them?

Comment: @Hogan yes, that is how I would like the output to look

Comment: The function header is missing, but it is an integral, essential part. Among other things we need to see the actual type of `v1`, as well as all parameters and the declared RETURN type. Also include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve with the function. To be certain we also need a table definition (`\d tbl` in psql). Can `value` be NULL in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT cast(t1.value as varchar(20)) || ', ' || cast(t2.value as varchar(20))
     INTO v1
     FROM table as t1, table as t2
     WHERE t1.year <= parameteryear
       AND t2.yearinteger >= parameteryear;
```

Comment: `+` is not used to concatenate strings in SQL

Comment: Thanks, that is much more compact, but I receive an `ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying + unknown`

Comment: @interpost - Sorry wrong platform.  see above -- you want `||` not `+`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - it is in some (well SQL Server for one)

Comment: The SQL standard defined back in 86 `||` as the string concatenation character and Postgres complies with the standard.

Comment: The query is only safe to use if the preconditions later added to the question are met: exactly one, not null value from each side is guaranteed. Still, casting to `varchar(20)` is pointless and possibly wrong. Use `text`or `varchar` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a union all query, it must be in a derived table.

```
select value
into v1
from (union query goes here) derivedTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Each individual statement is **dubious**, because `SELECT INTO` expects a **single row** to be returned, but your `WHERE` condition does not seem to guarantee that *at all*.

Combining both in a single statement is **even more dubious**, because you have all kinds of side effects if one of both is missing or NULL or not unique. Only makes sense if none of those complications can happen. I seriously doubt that.

If you can at least guarantee that you get values for both conditions, this would *work*:

```
SELECT concat_ws(',', t1.value, t2.value) 
INTO   v1
FROM   tbl t1, tbl t2
WHERE  t1.year <= parameteryear
AND    t2.yearinteger >= parameteryear;
```

But I am almost positive, it doesn't do what you want.
Also, judging from your "desired output" you may actually want a ***set*** of rows.

In short: The fragment you presented does not make any sense ***at all***. Post your complete code and what you actually trying to achieve. Most certainly, there is a different approach.

Comment: Yes, I realized after receiving Hogan's answer that I had oversimplified the code I posted.  Posting of the entire function would probably be excessive, but to add the missing context as you mentioned, there is a single row that is not null specified for these two `SELECT INTO` statements.

Comment: @interpost: Even then, there is probably a better solution. But let's leave this question at that.